# Update and selection operation at the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Table:

```
|E_NAME|COMPANY|POSITION|SALARY|
```

Tried:

```
UPDATE 
   COMPANY
SET 
   SALARY = SALARY + (SALARY * 0.05)
WHERE 
   ((POSITION = 'DOCTOR' OR POSITION = 'ENGINEER')
   AND SALARY < (SELECT AVG(SALARY) FROM COMPANY))
```

> MySQL Error: Table 'COMPANY' is specified twice, both as a target for
>   'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the average subquery in another subquery to get around this problem:

```
UPDATE COMPANY
SET SALARY = SALARY + (0.05 * SALARY)
WHERE
    POSITION IN ('DOCTOR', 'ENGINEER') AND
    SALARY < (SELECT avg_salary FROM
                 (SELECT AVG(SALARY) AS avg_salary FROM COMPANY) x);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you want a brief version, use: `SALARY = 1.05 * SALARY`

Comment: indeed you need  to use `1.05` in `SALARY = 1.05 * SALARY` not `0.05` as factor... Seams i need some more coffee..  i also would love to see `SALARY =* 1.05` as syntax sugar for `SALARY = 1.05 * SALARY` in the SQL standards by the way..

Answer (score 0):

Move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE COMPANY C CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT AVG(SALARY) AS AVG_SALARY FROM COMPANY) a
    SET C.SALARY = C.SALARY + (C.SALARY * 0.05)
WHERE POSITION IN ('DOCTOR', 'ENGINEER') AND
      C.SALARY < a.AVG_SALARY;
```

Note being able to reference the table being updated is a MySQL limitation.  Happily, it allows the use of `JOIN`s in `UPDATE`s (and `DELETE`s).